Certified NFC OEM module
I searched long time in the Meta threads to understand if my questions was on-topic (i.e. here and here) and it seems so. If not, please just tell me and I'll delete the question. No need for downvotes!

I'm looking for an OEM module (i.e. to be integrated in a product, connected to a PCB with MCU on-board) that allows to read an NFC tag (Mifare Classic 1k / NDEF).
On the Internet there are a lot of such a module (mostly based con PN532, like these) but they don't have any certifications. So if you need to certify your product will be a nightmare.
Here the features of the module I'm looking for:

OEM, that means with no enclosures, it will be soldered/connected to a bare PCB
communication with I2C (ideally) or UART/SPI
compatible with the common Mifare Classic 1k tag and Ultralight (NDEF)
with CE/RED/FCC certifications
the smaller the better!


Perhaps a NFC Reader/Writer Module SL060. From that webpage:

It has links to the following certification related reports:

SL060(ROHS2.0)
SL060_CE_Report
SL060_FCC_Report
SL060_ROHS_Report


The features list the following, which seems to match those from the question:



Category
Parameter




Tag supported
MIFARE Ultralight®, NTAG203, MIFARE Mini, MIFARE Classic® 1K, MIFARE Classic® 4K, FM11RF08, DESFire®


Integrated Antenna
Yes


Supply voltage
2.5 ~3.6 VDC


Dimension
46 × 46 × 3 mm


Operating distance
Up to 50mm, depending on tag




The website picture shows no enclosure.


I found it by the Google search nfc module site:fcc.report, i.e. search for nfc modules with reports on the FCC site. For the above module found NFC MIFARE MODULE SL060 User Manual which at the end had a Federal Communications Commission (FCC) Interference Statement. I just looked at one example from the search.
